# Lie algebra of the $\mathop{Spin}(4)$ group as 2-forms on tangent bundle

Tags: differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry

While trying to understand connections on spin manifolds, I stumbled over this (apparently obvious) statement.

Consider a spin $4$-manifold $M$. I am struggling to understand the intuition of the following statement: the Lie algebra of $\mathop{Spin}(4)$ is isomorphic to $\Lambda^2 TM$. Is there any reason as to why is this natural to consider?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Given the usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ , is it clear that $\mathfrak{so}(n)\cong\Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @Kajelad Yes, both are traceless skew $n\times n$ matrices if you choose coordinates, for example. Then, of course, the Lie algebra of $SO(n)$ coincides with the Lie algebra of $Spin(n)$. I believe that you accurately pinpointed the more basic problem: your statement is mathematically obvious, but it does not make intuitive sense to me, why is the Lie algebra of the structural group exactly the set of $2$-forms. Am I searching for too much meaning from a basic fact?

Comment: The same linear algebra applies in this more abstract setting: if you have a Lie group $G$ acting linearly on a vector space $V$, its lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ canonically acts by endomorphisms on $V$. Endomorphisms are not skew forms, but an inner product allows one to identify the space of endomorphisms and the space of bilinear forms (by "lowering an index"). Under this identification, the Lie algebra of the orthogonal group corresponds exactly to the set of skew-symmetric forms.

Comment: @Kajelad This makes a lot more sense now, thank you! I think that this answers my question.